# Constructing `telethon.tl.custom.message.Message` from message dumped as dict

Tags: python, telethon

`telethon.tl.custom.message.Message` supports `to_dict()` function, when I create a new `Message` instance using the same `id` and `message` fields from that message dict I am able to create a `Message` object, but when trying to send the message to channel I get this error `TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable`.

```
    message = add_surrogate(message)
  File "/Users/barha/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 39, in add_surrogate
    return ''.join(
TypeError: 'Message' object is not iterable
```

is there a formal way to construct the `Message` from dumped dict? Any hints about the send message of custom `Message` error?

Comment: There's no builtin way to go from a `dict` back to the `Message`. It's probably easier to just specify the required parameters in `send_message`.

Comment: @Lonami, I see it is `send_message` supports `textual message`, and `send_file` to send image, what if I want to send image that has text in the same message? (https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html), - ok I found `file` attribute for `send_message`